# How do I "Show Documentation" in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I'm looking for the equivalent to CTRL-Q of IntelliJ, that shows you the documentation for the current code.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've never used IntelliJ, so not sure it's an exact equivalent, but when I press <kbd>F2</kbd> in Eclipse, I have a popup that displays some help.

For example, here, I pressed <kbd>F2</kbd> as my pointer was on `Log` :

[image]
<sub>(source: [pascal-martin.fr](http://extern.pascal-martin.fr/so/5302853.png))</sub>

Comment: Yes pressing `F2` will open documentation. I was also looking for the same. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: This does not work if the location is marked by another marker, e.g. a compile error or a plugin that marks the location (Sonarlint, etc.). Pressing F2 in these cases will open the corresponding tool tip, so quick fixes for compile errors and rule description for Sonarlint. The IntelliJ shortcut always opens the documentation and an equivalent shortcut in Eclipse would be really helpful exactly because the mouse-over popup is overriden by this other information.

Comment: What's the name of the 'action' of F2? I've rebound F2 so I cannot look it up. \[edit] found it! "**Show Tooltip Description**"

Answer (score 2):

To see the attached Javadoc of a class, you can open the Javadoc view in another panel by pressing `Alt + Shift + Q, J` (as described in this [answer](http://To%20see%20the%20attached%20Javadoc%20of%20a%20class,%20you%20can%20open%20the%20Javadoc%20view%20in%20another)). Alternatively, select "Window -> Show View -> Other -> Java -> Javadoc". The view will be updated with the selection in the code editor and will show the Javadoc for the method, class or even field at the cursor position.

I don't know if there is anything similar for other languages though.